# how to import Auto CAD in ArcMap?

Tags: openlayers-3, arcgis, autocad, arcmap

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1 and want to import auto CAD object .
I follow this way :
insert>import object

but there is an error :

> "failed to create object. make sure the object is insert in the system
>   registry?"

after search in google and find this [answer](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000007145) , I disabled my Anti Virus but when I try to import Auto Cad after that ArcMap didn't work and I closed then try again and again but i can't to do this.
-can someone help me to Import Auto CAD to ArcMap ?
-I wan to change the format of auto CAD to geoJSON to work with my drawings in openlayers 3.

Comment: Not sure this is a question for SO?

Comment: when you say AutoCAD you mean a dwg file ? I agree with @TedNyberg GIS SE would be a better place to ask your question

Comment: thank u for answeryng
yes, that means dwg.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Using Insert > Object you will add the object to the layout of the map. If you want to add it to your map as a layer, just drag & drop the dwg in the display, from the Catalog window.

Comment: i did this but there was an error
"failed to create object.Make sure the object is entered in the system registry "

Answer (score 0):

you have two solutions:

1. you can drag and drop your dwf file from arccatalaog or windows explorer to your arcmap project
2. you can use datainteroperability extension and import your dwg file to a file or personal geodatabase.

It will work !!